# Dynamically iterate through a json array and add to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a large array of json objects, that I need to iterate through and add them to another json array.

The array looks like the following -

```
{
  id : 1,
  name : "test1",
  location : "London",
  cost: "120.83"
},
{
  id : 2,
  name : "test2",
  location : "shanghai",
  cost: "124.83"
},
{
  id : 3,
  name : "test3",
  location : "Barcelona",
  cost: "56.54"
}
```

The actual array that im using has 73 key, value pairs, and about 20000 objects.

I am trying to transpose each individual object into another array, that needs to look like -

```
{
  cells: 
    [
       {
         value: 1,
         textAlign: "center",
         background: "rgb(255,255,255)",
         color: "rgb(0,62,117)"
       },
       {
         value: "test1",
         textAlign: "center",
         background: "rgb(255,255,255)",
         color: "rgb(0,62,117)"
       },
       {
         value: "London",
         textAlign: "center",
         background: "rgb(255,255,255)",
         color: "rgb(0,62,117)"
       },
       {
         value: "120.83",
         textAlign: "center",
         background: "rgb(255,255,255)",
         color: "rgb(0,62,117)"
       },
    ]
},
{
  cells: 
    [
       {
          value: 2,
          textAlign: "center",
          background: "rgb(255,255,255)",
          color: "rgb(0,62,117)"
       },
       {
          value: "test2",
          textAlign: "center",
          background: "rgb(255,255,255)",
          color: "rgb(0,62,117)"
       },
       {
          value: "shanghai",
          textAlign: "center",
          background: "rgb(255,255,255)",
          color: "rgb(0,62,117)"
       },
       {
          value: "124.83",
          textAlign: "center",
          background: "rgb(255,255,255)",
          color: "rgb(0,62,117)"
       },
   ]
},
```

I just cant get my head around it, it must be the monday fog!

Thanks

Comment: how do they relate to each other? please add a consitent example.

Comment: When giving example input & expected output, make it valid.  It stops all the questions later.  Looking at your input & output, I've a feeling you have put 1 too many items in the input example.

Comment: @NinaScholz they are related, op is mapping each value of each object to a element in calls array

Comment: the actual fields and values are irrelevant for this example, its just the actual way of transposing i am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const data = [
  { id : 1, name : "test1", location : "London", cost: "120.83" },
  { id : 2, name : "test2", location : "shanghai", cost: "124.83" },
  { id : 3, name : "test3", location : "Barcelona", cost: "56.54" }
];

const cell = { textAlign: 'center', background: 'rgb(255,255,255)', color: 'rgb(0,62,117)' };

const result = data.map(x =>
  ({ cells: Object.values(x).map(v => ({ value: `${v}`, ...cell })) })
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let arr = [{id:1,name:"test1",location:"London",cost:"120.83"},{id:2,name:"test2",location:"shanghai",cost:"124.83"},{id:3,name:"test3",location:"Barcelona",cost:"56.54"}]

let defaultObject = {textAlign: "center",background: "rgb(255,255,255)",color: "rgb(0,62,117)" }

let op = arr.map(e => Object.values(e).reduce((op,inp) => {
    op.cells.push({value: inp, ...defaultObject } )
    return op
  },{cells:[]})
)

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` and `Object.assign()` methods:

```js
const data = [
  {id : 1, name : "test1", location : "London", cost: "120.83"},
  {id : 2, name : "test2", location : "shanghai", cost: "124.83"},
  {id : 3, name : "test3", location : "Barcelona", cost: "56.54"}
];

const obj = {
  textAlign: "center",
  background: "rgb(255,255,255)",
  color: "rgb(0,62,117)"
};

const result = data.map(o => ({
   cells: Object.keys(o).map(k => Object.assign({}, {value: o[k]}, obj))
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```